# google app engine not able to connect to outlook mailbox

Tags: google-app-engine, exception, outlook, jakarta-mail, imap

I are trying to read emails from an outlook mailbox using javamail api.  The protocol for this mail reading is imap. Google SDK comes with java mail API but it doesn’t support imap protocol. For the purpose I need to include java mail api libraries in pom.xml. Now there are two copies of javamail api in app engine project, one that comes with google sdk and the other one from pom.xml. During execution of java code to connect to mailserver, app engine is not able make a connection sometimes. The behavior is not consistent as GAE might be loading java mail api in random order.  When GAE doesn't connect to mailbox, i see the following error:

javax.mail.MessagingException: No login methods supported! 
(com.sun.mail.iap.ProtocolException: No login methods supported!)

```
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:477)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:248)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:91)
at com.disney.util.MailBoxConnector.connect(MailBoxConnector.java:48)
```

I could not find a workaround for this problem. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error suggests that it **is** finding the IMAP protocol support.  Are you sure you're making an SSL connection?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show when it fails?

Comment: i am using props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory") before connection.

Comment: [Don't do that.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes)

Comment: Bill, Thanks for the response. I see the stated exception, while running the code in google app engine, that too sometimes. My understanding is google app engine has its own javamail api which can clash with mail.jar included in pom.xml. but i am not able to replicate the process. the code works in one cloud environment and starts giving trouble in other. i also tried the things you recommended above, still not comfortable if the code will not give this error again. there is a java standalone version of this code, and i have never seen this problem there.

Comment: I have no experience with GAE but there must be some way to tell it to use the JavaMail jar file included in your application instead of the one provided by GAE.  And I have no idea why it would work sometimes but not always.